# Can I move an LVM as I can move an ISO

Tags: backup, lvm

Can an LVM be copied or transferred to some remote server in a similar
fashion as
I can do with ISO.(Not asking rsync)

I copy the ISO one one place to some other location and on the second location
I can mount this ISO and do what ever I want.
Is similar thing possible with an LVM.
I want to move the complete block device to some remote location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move PVs. Using them in a remote location is tricky if a VG is spread across multiple PVs though. It's much easier to just move the LVs and use them as you would any filesystem file.